# Не работает .appendChild() в место .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, ajax

Дамы и Господа, есть  такой `ajax` код:

```
    function ajax(url, callback, data, request) {
    try {
        request = new(this.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        request.open(data ? 'POST' : 'GET', url, 1);
        request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            request.readyState > 3 && callback && callback(request.responseText, request);
        };
        request.send(data)
    } catch (e) {
        window.console && console.log(e);
    }
};
```

в отдельной папке.

И в отдельной папке такой JS файл `main.js`:

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const iDroot = document.getElementById('root');
        ajax('../pages/index.html', function(res) {
            iDroot.appendChild(res);
        })
    const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    console.log('wrapper');   
});
```

Если в место строчки `iDroot.appendChild(res);` написать `iDroot.innerHTML = 'res';`, то все работает.

Объясните, почему в данном случае `.innerHTML` работает, а `.appendChild()` нет?

Больше всего смущает, что в консоли `wrapper` видит.
В консоли показывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: appendChild ожидает Node, ты пытаешься туда вставить String... вроде ошибка же красноречиво намекает.

Comment: Если бы я столько понимал....  Слушай, а будь другом, объясни, в данном примере, что грамотней использовать или правильней или нет особого значения...?  Хотя значение есть, вдруг если мне придется вставить какой нибудь кусок туда куда надо, а без ` .appendChild() `  этого не сделаешь...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде, тут: `ajax('../pages/index.html', function(res) {`

В аргумент callback функции `res` будет передана строка (браузер посылает http get запрос, получает ответ. Тело ответа - это всегда просто `String`).

После чего, при вызове `.appendChild(res)` браузер пытается добавить содержимое переменной `res`, предполагая что это экземпляр Node в конец списка дочерних элементов родителя. Но оказывается, что это строка, поэтому выбрасывается соответствующая ошибка `parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`.

В случае использования `element.innerHTML = '...'` - браузер распарсит переданную строку, попытается на ее основе создать новые узлы Dom, и вставит их внутрь элемента.

*Про appendChild:
[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild_)*

*Про innerHTML:
[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML_)*

Comment: kaluginserg, привет, а как мне тогда выйти из ситуации, если мне надо `ajax-ом` вставить элемент в определенное место... `innerHTML `  тут не помощник

Comment: Попробуй например через createElement: let newElem = document.createElement();  newElem.innerHTML = ajaxStringHtml;  targetElem.appendChild(newElem);

Comment: Вопрос такой...  Получается, что  `ajax-ом` я могу что-то куда-то  засунуть только методом `innerHTML`?

Comment: Собственно чем именно не подходит innerHTML?? В этой ветке есть разные варианты создания элемента из строки:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)